# Clear empty arrays from a 2d Array

Tags: google-apps-script

I have an array -

```
[[Rice, 125.0, 5000.0, Sat Dec 30 01:23:24 GMT-06:36 1899], [, , , ], [, , , ], [, , , ], [, , , ], [, , , ], [, , , ], [, , , ]]
```

I am needing to remove the empty arrays from the end of the array how can I do this?

Comment: `yourArr.filter(a => a.filter(b => b != null && b != '').length > 0)`

Comment: you got it method clearEmpty . Returns clear array .

Answer (score 3):

A slightly more elegant way would be to filter via Boolean

```
inputArr.filter(function(a) {
  return a.filter(Boolean).length > 0;
});
```

Comment: Arrow functions are not supported in Google Apps Script, so this can only yield `SyntaxError` for OP.

Comment: Worked for me in my app script.

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is `join` the inner array with respect to `""` so that if there are any values in that array then it will not result to `""`. Thus, you can compare this condition and create a new array in `res` variable:

```js
var inputArray = [['Rice', 125.0, 5000.0, 'Sat Dec 30 01:23:24 GMT-06:36 1899'], [ , , ], [ , , ], [ , , ], [ , , ]];

var res = inputArray.filter(
    innerArray => innerArray.join("") !== "" 
);
 
console.log(res);
```

Comment: @BrandonHunt what's the error? The array is exactly what you have in your question and this is running well in snippet.

Comment: all it says is "Syntax error. (line 32, file "Code")"

Comment: Does other answers work for you @BrandonHunt or is it just mine answer which is giving you error?

Comment: @AnkitAgarwal use only features available in Google Apps Script (i.e. JS 1.6) and you can remove the SyntaxError. Basically, arrow functions are not allowed.

Comment: Impressive solution!

Answer (score 0):

You could check for existent items and adjust the length of the array for removing sparse arrays from the end.

```js
var array = [['some data', 42], [0, , , ], [, , , ], [, , , ], [, , , ], [, , , ], [, , , ], [, , , ]],
    i = array.length;
    
while (i--) {
    if (array[i].some(function () { return true; })) {
        break;
    }
    array.length = i;
}

console.log(array);
```

Comment: This works if the array is truly empty, i.e. `[, , , ]`, but will obviously fail for loose definitions of "empty", i.e. contains 0-length strings, sub-arrays, etc, e.g. `[0, "", "", ""]`. OP gave an example with `, , ,` so seems OK, as long as you indicate that caveat. Also maybe mention that this will not trim out any empty (truly or not) sub-arrays that are not at the end, e.g. `[["my", "data", "is", "here"], [, , , ], ["and", "here", "too", 42]]`

Comment: @tehhowch, op stated *"to remove the empty arrays from the end"*, which mean, that empty arrays inside should be kept, or so.

Comment: Indeed, that's why I mentioned it works exactly as OP asked it to. As we know, OP is not the only one who will find this code (especially if marked as the answer), and without caveats in the answer (who reads comments? :D ) there will no doubt be some who wonder why the function does not work like they think it should. It's also possible the OP unintentionally mis-phrased their question or their example (because `, , , ` is much easier to type than `"", "", "", ""`...)

Answer (score 0):

Here is solution !
 Enjoy !

```js
var test = [['Rice', 125.0, 5000.0, 'Sat Dec 30 01:23:24 GMT-06:36 1899'], [, , , ], [, , , ], [, , , ], [, , , ], [, , , ], [, , , ], [, , , ]];

console.log(test.length)

for (var x = test.length-1; x > 0; x--)  {
 
  // console.log(test[x][0] )
  
  if ( test[x][0] === undefined ) {
  
       test.splice(  x, 1 )
       
  }

}

console.log(test)

// METHOD  Use it test = clearEmpty(test)
function clearEmpty ( arrayForClear ) {

for (var x = arrayForClear.length-1; x > 0; x--)  {
  if ( arrayForClear[x][0] === undefined ) {
       arrayForClear(  x, 1 )
  }
}
 return arrayForClear;

}
```

Comment: This may be a Google Script issue but when I get the array from a script (i.e. SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getRangeByName('vaProductionData').getValues();) this does not work. But if I copy the log of the array found here it works perfectly. I am sooo confused.

Comment: Use debugger and see what is "SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getRangeByName('vaProductionData').getValues"